# Inserting Winforms Form inside XAML WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, interop

I'm trying to integrate a WinForms Form inside a WPF XAML page.
I have seen examples of putting Windows Forms controls using WindowsFormsHost, but not for integrating a whole form.

Is there a way to do it? The Windows form is hosted inside the WPF application and I'm currently able to load it as a new window but not inside the XAML page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put a WinForms form inside a WindowsFormsHost tag in a WPF Form is an error.  But you can instantiate a new form from any WPF Project.  Here's how:

Say you have two projects "WinFormProj" and "WPFProj".  WinFormProj has a form called "Login".

First add a reference in the WPFProj project to WinFormProj.

Then behind any event in any WPFProj element, do this:

```
var winFormWindow = new WinFormProj.Login();  
winFormWindow.Show();  
// or  
windFormWindow.ShowDialog();
```

If that won't do, you can convert your WinForms form to a user control which **will** exist just great in a WindowsFormsHost WPF tag.  To do that, it is often as simple as ...

Go to the class declaration and change:

```
public class Login : Form
```

to

```
public class Login : UserControl
```

Next, in your WPF form, add the WinForms project as an xml namespace:

```
xmlns:winForms="clr-namespace:WinFormsProj;assembly=WinFormsProj"
```

And finally, add this to your Grid/StackPanel/Whatever where you want the user control to be hosted:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="LoginControl">
    <winForms:LogIn />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Pretty simple once you demystify it.